# Adding an empty newline after a comment block in bash code using sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to reformat a series of rather large bash scripts using sed.

They contain a lot of code that looks something like this:

```
# first comment goes here

# second comment goes here
if [[ -n "$some_variable" ]]; then
    do_something
fi
```

or:

```
# first comment goes here

# second comment goes here
# third comment goes here
if [[ -n "$some_variable" ]]; then
    do_something
fi
```

How can I leverage sed to add a newline in-between a comment (so a line that starts with #) and any non-comment code, like so?:

```
# first comment goes here

# second comment goes here
                                      <--- newline inserted here by sed
if [[ -n "$some_variable" ]]; then
    do_something
fi
```

or, for the second example:

```
# first comment goes here

# second comment goes here
# third comment goes here
                                      <--- newline inserted here by sed
if [[ -n "$some_variable" ]]; then
    do_something
fi
```

Comment: Why do you want to use sed for that? It'd probably be clearer, simpler, more portable, etc. with awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\s*#/{:a;n;//ba;/\S/{x;p;x}}' file
```

If a line begins with a comment, print it and fetch the next line.

If the that line begins with a comment, repeat above.

Otherwise, if the line is not empty, print an empty line.

Always print the current line.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '{pCom=cCom; cCom=/^#/} NF && !cCom && pCom{$0=ORS $0} 1' file
# first comment goes here

# second comment goes here

if [[ -n "$some_variable" ]]; then
    do_something
fi

or:

# first comment goes here

# second comment goes here
# third comment goes here

if [[ -n "$some_variable" ]]; then
    do_something
fi
```

The above was run on this input file:

```
$ cat file
# first comment goes here

# second comment goes here
if [[ -n "$some_variable" ]]; then
    do_something
fi

or:

# first comment goes here

# second comment goes here
# third comment goes here
if [[ -n "$some_variable" ]]; then
    do_something
fi
```

If you prefer your scripts more indecipherable you could write the above as:

```
awk '{p=c;c=/^#/}NF&&!c&&p{$0=ORS$0}1' file
```

Comment: wouldn't `NF && c < p` be cleaner ? or even `( p <= c ) < NF ` or `c < ( p * NF )`

Answer (score 0):

Looks simple.

```
sed '/^[^ \t]*\(#\|$\)/{
     { 
        :comment
        n
        //bcomment
     }
     s/^/\n/
}'
```

Comment: You should mention which version(s) of sed that'll work in (it doesn't insert the blank lines with GNU sed when you add `--posix` so there's some non-portable construct in there but idk what).

Answer (score 0):

```
for __ in 

   '# first comment goes here
    
    # second comment goes here
    if [[ -n "$some_variable" ]]; then
        do_something
    fi' 

   '# first comment goes here   

    # second comment goes here
    # third comment goes here
    if [[ -n "$some_variable" ]]; then
        do_something
    fi'               ; do printf '%s' "$__" |
```

---

> ```
> mawk 'NF-!_ || ($!NF = RS $_)(FS = "$")' FS='^#'
> ```

---

```
done

     1  # first comment goes here
     2  
     3  # second comment goes here
     4  
     5  if [[ -n "$some_variable" ]]; then
     6  
     7      do_something
     8  
     9  fi

     1  # first comment goes here   
     2  
     3  # second comment goes here
     4  # third comment goes here         
     5  
     6  if [[ -n "$some_variable" ]]; then
     7  
     8      do_something              
     9  
    10  fi
```